# changing password with .htpasswd resulting in error 404

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

In the past I configured apache/phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 12.4 server with htaccess to protect phpmyadmin. Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu). I have forgot the password.

Config file shows this.

```
root@localhost:/usr/share/phpmyadmin# cat .htaccess
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
root@localhost:/usr/share/phpmyadmin#
```

Now when I try to change password using

```
root@localhost:/usr/share/phpmyadmin# htpasswd  -c /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd root
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user root
```

and login to phpmyadmin by entering user/pass, it then shows

```
404 File Not Found
```

How can I remove password protection in phpMyAdmin to access it?

Comment: are you sure that apache has its document root set to: /usr/share/phpmyadmin for phpmyadmin? And can you verify that /usr/share/phpmyadmin contains files except for the .htaccess?

Comment: I am abit confused. there are lot of folder. which one to check for document root?
  root@localhost:/etc/apache2# ls /etc/apache2/  
  apache2.conf
  conf-enabled
  magic
  mods-enabled
  sites-available
  ssl
  conf-available
  envvars
  mods-available
  ports.conf
  sites-enabled

Comment: Probably sites-enabled has a virtual host for phpmyadmin. Otherwise go to /etc/apache2/ and run: grep -ri phpmyadmin and you will probably find a file that has the configuration. In that file you check where the document root points to. Then you check if that directory has contents for phpmyadmin application files.

Comment: root@localhost:/etc/apache2# ls sites-enabled/  > 
000-default.conf  81.conf  default-ssl.conf
-------------------------------------------------------
grep command returns nothing -------------------------------------------------------
root@localhost:/etc/apache2# grep -ri phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove password protection :

run

```
cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin
sudo vim .htaccess
```

then comment the line that says `Require valid-user` so it looks like this

```
#Require valid-user
```